# why data reader didn't serve all result fields from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

[image]

I have written a stored procedure for getting details from database table. While executing that stored procedure, I get the correct results, but on my page, I only get 5 out of 6 column values from the stored procedure output. I only get values up to `dataReader[4]:`

```
public List<User> ShowDetailsFromDB()
{
    using (adoHelper = new AdoHelper(connectionString))
    {
        List<User> users = new List<User>();
        string procedureName = "GetDetails";

        SqlDataReader dataReader = adoHelper.ExecuteDataReaderByProcedure(procedureName);

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            User user = new User();
            user.userId = dataReader[0] as string;
            user.password = dataReader[1] as string;
            user.userName = dataReader[2] as string;
            user.email = dataReader[3] as string;
            user.phone = dataReader[4] as string;                  
            user.userRegId = dataReader[5] as string;
            users.Add(user);
        }

        return users;
    }
}



USE [TryLocal]
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetDetails]
as
begin
select 
registration.UserId,
registration.Password,
registration.UserName,
registration.Email,
registration.Phone,
registration.RegID
from  Registration registration
Right JOIN dbo.UserAddress useraddress ON 
registration.RegID=useraddress.UserRegId
group by
registration.UserId,registration.Password,registration.UserName,
registration.Email,
registration.Phone,
registration.RegID
order by(registration.UserName)
end
```

Comment: *i only get 4 out of 5 column* means there is only 5 columns means your data reader will have `0..4`

Comment: Check your Data type for 'user.userRegId' I belive it is integer.. You may be casting it to different data type..

Comment: Please show your SP.

Comment: @karthickj25 user.userRegId is a string

Comment: Do you get an error or a blank value?

Comment: @DaleBurrell i got null value in dataReader[5]

Comment: That tells you its either a datatype mismatch or null is stored in the database. - because if column 5 wasn't being returned you'd get an error. Try using `ToString()` instead of `as string`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
user.userRegId = dataReader[5] as string;
```

**datareader[5] is not a string!** It's an integer, and in C# you can't just cast from int to string; it wants to be aware of the different culture and formatting options, where a cast to string is ambiguous. Therefore the `as` operator here will always produce `null`.

Instead you can call `dataReader[5].ToString()`, or `dataReader.GetInt32(5)`, or `(int)dataReader[5]`. I would expect any of those to work. And if there's any chance this field could be `NULL` in the database you also want to check for `DBNull.Value` somewhere.

---

While I'm here... plain text passwords in the database are **NOT OKAY**, not even for testing or learning. If you're doing this just as a learning system for practice, *build something that doesn't need authentication*.